# Why is game time shortened by half instead of 2 seconds?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to build a game in pure JavaScript as an exercise.

The game purpose is to answer a random math exercise before a timer runs out. The time is represented by an egg that falls on someones head; if you answered all of the math exercises correctly, you will start over, but the time will be shortened by 2 seconds.

My problem: During level 1 of the game, the time works as expected, but by level 2 time is getting shorter by half. What is causing this to happen?

Related code:

```
var gameTime;
//function responsible for starting The game
function StartGame() {  
    ...
    ...
    ...
    checkLevel();
    getNewTime();        
    speed=getNewSpeed();
   dh=setInterval("move(egg)",gameTime);
    ...             
}//End start game

function checkLevel() {
   
   if(document.getElementById("begginer").checked==true) {
        fillNumbervalue(true);
        gameTime=30;                   
       }
    else  {        
        fillNumbervalue(false); 
          gameTime=60;    
    } //End else   
}//End of checkLevel

function getNewSpeed () {    
    return (distanceBetweenEggToYudale/gameTime); //distanceBetweenEggToYudale=310
}//End function
    
//if player pass level this function will get down by 2 seconds the time
function getNewTime() {
    for(var i=0;i<levelCount;i++)
              gameTime-=2;
}//end getNewTime

//function responsible for moving The Egg
function move(eggBall) {    
    eggBall.imagePositionY=eggBall.imagePositionY+(gameTime/1000)*speed;  
 //image postion=0 at the beginning
    eggBall.element.style.top=eggBall.imagePositionY+"px";       
   ...
   ...     
}//End move

//when the player push the answer button
function answerValidation() {
        var answers=new Array();        
            for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++)
                answers[i]=document.getElementById("txtAnswer"+(i+1)).value;        
    
                if(result[0]!=answers[0] || result[1]!=answers[1] || result[2]!=answers[2])                  
                    gameOverScreen();                     
                else 
                {
                   score++;
                   levelCount++;                   
                   init(); //Initial the egg position onload of the body element
                   clearTxtRows();                   
                   gameTime-=2;  
                    
                   StartGame();      
                }//End else  
             
          
    }//End anwser validation
```

I know this question is loaded with code, so I would really appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: Good job with your efforts. Please work on your typing and grammar. Having a question that is clear and concise includes having a well-written and *personally edited* question. This helps others see that you are serious. :)

Comment: Also, kudos on labeling it homework. :D

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're reusing your `gameTime` variable, when what you want to do is start at the same time and decrement from that. So you want a `startGameTime` variable.

With only a `gameTime` variable:

http://jsfiddle.net/DPTJ3/1/

With a `startGameTime` variable to restart the `gameTime` value before decrement:

http://jsfiddle.net/DPTJ3/

```
function getNewTime() {
    gameTime = startGameTime;
    for (var i = 0; i < levelCount; i++) {
        gameTime -= 2;
    }
}

function logData() {
    log = document.getElementById('log');
    log.innerHTML += "LEVEL: " + levelCount + "\nGTIME: " + gameTime + "\n\n";
}

var levelCount = 1;
var startGameTime = 60;
var gameTime = 60;

logData();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    levelCount++;
    getNewTime();
    logData();
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
LEVEL: 1
GTIME: 60

LEVEL: 2
GTIME: 56

LEVEL: 3
GTIME: 54

LEVEL: 4
GTIME: 52

LEVEL: 5
GTIME: 50

LEVEL: 6
GTIME: 48

LEVEL: 7
GTIME: 46

LEVEL: 8
GTIME: 44

LEVEL: 9
GTIME: 42

LEVEL: 10
GTIME: 40

LEVEL: 11
GTIME: 38
```

**EDIT**

Also, if you want to *accurately* decrement, you should probably account for the fact that the first level is really 0 instead of one *to the getNewTime() function*. If you notice, it seems to decrement the first by two level degrees. To resolve this, you can:

```
for (var i = 0; i < levelCount - 1; i++) { // Notice the - 1
```

Comment: when i put "alert(gameTime)" and alert("speed") to check if the variables value  was ok.
ouput:
gameTime=30 in level 1
gameTime=28.... in level 2

i tried to do what u told me but it did not work.I thought that maybe the problem is here:
egg.imagePosition=egg.imagePosition+(speed/1000)*gameTime 
any suggestions?
ps.English is my second Language so i will try to work on my grammar :)

Comment: @liron - First, you need to use `console` (in Firefox, use Firebug, in Chrome, it's already there). Second, your approach to determining each level's time was flawed (as I demonstrate above). The egg position should not determine the level game time (think about it), it is simply a factor of the current level's game play. If you have an online version of your game, that would help.

Comment: If it would be more Convenient for you i can try upload this "game" to a free webSite host !?

Comment: @liron - Looking at the full code, I think the real issue has to do with the method of moving the egg and detecting the collision with Yudale's head. See here: http://jfcoder.com/test/calcGame/Main.htm Note, I've changed several things, including reformatting the code for my own readability. What I did was create two new variables for the egg displacement: incrementTime, and incrementUnit. (see next comment)

Comment: incrementTime represents the time in milliseconds that feeds setInterval; this will make it run consistently. incrementUnit is a function of the distance to travel with gameTime and incrementTime factored in. Additionally, I created some debug variables (startTime and endTime) so I could check the running time (these use console.log(), either use Firebug in FF or Chrome, which has console built-in). The running time told me if it was accurate. Your choice of 30 seconds just happened to coincide with the flawed calculation you were using, which is why the time seemed to work, but didn't.

Comment: Something to note is that the intervalTime setting is fairly accurate down to about 100 milliseconds; below that, it starts getting more and more out of sync. I believe this is because of browser speeds and Javascript being single-threaded - doing the egg calculation and moving the egg causes the step to take longer than 10 milliseconds, so each cycle is not accurate, causing the entire process to slow down (significantly at 10 milliseconds). So you might try to use another approach (such as using a time interval check where the egg should be, not how far it should move per cycle).

Comment: One more thing, my debug variable short-circuits the answer check, so I could then just click the button to check the next level's time. This was easier and less frustrating than trying to answer the questions. :D Setting debug = false should allow it to run correctly once you're ready to debut it.